# displaying each line with a different color inside TextArea

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer

I am developing an ASP.NET website where I have TextArea and I need to set different color for each line.

I have the following in my code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Max_Senses; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        if (j == 0) //first line black
             TextArea1.Attributes["Style"] = "FONT-FAMILY: ''consolas';FONT-STYLE:bold; COLOR: Black; BACKGROUND-COLOR: White";
        else // other lines red
             TextArea1.Attributes["Style"] = "FONT-FAMILY: 'consolas';FONT-STYLE:bold; COLOR: Red; BACKGROUND-COLOR: White";

        TextArea1.Value += res[k, j].PadRight(11);
    }

    TextArea1.Value += "\r\n";
}
```

It displays all lines with red while I need the first line to be colored black! Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The HTML `TextArea` does not support this. You likely will need a control that supports `ContentEditable`, like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: is this the only way to do that?

Comment: its by far one of the simplest.

Comment: This didn't work! it displays only the last specified color!!